# How to join 2 dataframe that have the same data?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How to join 2 dataframes which have the same song name and I want to join them together by using the song name, I want it to go through every rows that have the same song[image]

[image: this is my 2 dataframes]

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
pd.merge(left=one, right=two, how='left', left_on='Song', right_on='Song')
```